# Performing Arthimetic to all values in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, math

My question is how to do math operations to all the values in an array. I've been doing the whole for looping for each value, but it just made me wonder if there was some easier way to type it out, and/or something that increases performance.

For example:

```
int[] numbers;
numbers[0] = 0;
numbers[1] = 1;
```

Now, I'm not entirely concerned with taking [0] and [1], and adding or subtracting them. More like, how do I add 3 to all of them, without using a loop?

Comment: Your array instantiating needs to be `int[] numbers = new int[2];`

Comment: Yah, I'm not really savy. Thank god MS Visual C# tells you where you suck. I was just fleshing it out for others to read so it might makes sense.

Comment: NP. Also, instead of using arrays, I would just use a list: `var numbers = new List<int>(); numbers.Add(0);numbers.Add(1);` then you don't have to worry about the size and have alot more functions available to you

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to apply a function to all values in an Enumerable (for example array or List).

```
var result = numbers.Select(i => i + 3);
```

This is the full code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var numbers = new int[2] {0,1};

        var result = numbers.Select(i => i + 3);

        result.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    numbers = numbers.Select(i => i +3).ToArray();

    foreach(var numb in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numb);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here it will add 3 to every element of the array.

Comment: Well, i'll admit, I learned something by your post, but its still not what I'm looking for. I was hoping for something like "numbers + 3" and call it a night.

Comment: I don't know what to say about your hopes. This is how you can do it with LINQ.

Comment: I do appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily efficient or in any way better than simply looping (ultimately, that's what needs to happen at a low level regardless of the approach), but Linq is one way to go about a one-liner approach if that's what you're after.

```
var numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
var newNumbers = numbers.Select(n=> n+3).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add: projecting with **.Select** + **.ToArray** will initialize a new collection , whereas **.ForEach** will modify the elements in place.

Answer (score -3):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

As long as your math does not need to happen sequentially you can multithread

```
Parallel.ForEach(numbers, (number) =>{
    number+=3;
});
```

Comment: Man, a nice try, but it will not work, number is a value variable, thus it's not being assigned to the array :D

Comment: `namespace TestArea
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            numbers = numbers.Select(i => i + 3).ToArray();

            
                Parallel.ForEach(numbers, (number) => {
                    number += 3;
                });

            numbers.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

        }
    }
}` Produces "4, 5, 6" in my console app.